# d3.js updating text only works when taking away text not when adding dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, heatmap

The following is my update function for a heatmap that monitors different databases on different servers. SchemaTables is a combined variable of the schema it is referencing and the table within the schema it's referencing. The function is within a dictionary named heatmap which contains other functions as well. For some reason when taking away rows, the y-value axis fixes themselves accordingly, however when adding rows a couple of errors pop up as explained in the following code and comments:

```
update: function(usingFilter=false, schemaTableFilter=0) {
        // get functions get most recent data
        var data = getData(),
        servers = getServers(),
        schemaTables = getSchemaTables(),
        //constants
        gridSize = {height: 35, width: 140},
        colors = ["#E50000", "#E45500", "#E3A900", "#C7E200", "#72E100", "#1DE00D", "#00E036"],
        width = 460 + (gridSize.width * columns),
        height = 400 + (gridSize.height * rows),
        columns = servers.length,
        rows = schemaTables.length;

        //Fit HTML
        $("html").height(height);
        $("html").width(width);
        $("svg").height(height);
        $("svg").width(width);

        var svg = d3.select("g");
        //User has the option to use a filter, if a filter is 
        //used then weed out whatever shouldn't be shown.
        if (usingFilter) {
                schemaTables = schemaTableFilter;
                data = getFilteredData($("#filters").val());
        }

        //x-axis labels - the amount of servers doesn't really change
        //so as far as I know this works, but perhaps not 
        var serverLabels = svg.selectAll(".serverLabel")
            .data(servers)
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .exit().remove()
            .enter().append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize.width})
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize.width / 2 + ", -6)")
                .attr("class", "serverLabel mono")

        //y-axis labels - where I'm having trouble
        //It works when taking away rows but not when adding
        var schemaTableLabels = svg.selectAll(".schemaTableLabel")
            console.log(schemaTableLabels);
            schemaTableLabels.data(schemaTables).text(function (d) { return d; })
            .exit().remove()
            .enter().append("text")
                .attr("x", 50)
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize.height; })
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize.height / 1.5 + ")")
                .attr("class", "schemaTableLabel mono")

        //If removing rows no error occurs, if adding rows then 
        //I get an Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
        var gridAmount = servers.length * schemaTables.length,
            coordinates = Array(gridAmount).join(".").split(".");

        //This for loop puts the data at the correct x, y coordinates
        //within a list
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var serverIndex = servers.indexOf(data[i].server);
            var schemaTableIndex = schemaTables.indexOf(data[i].schemaTable);
            var index = (schemaTables.length * serverIndex) + (schemaTableIndex % schemaTables.length)
            var currentData = data[i];
            coordinates[index] = currentData;
        }

        //This for loop makes sure each index has an x, y 
        //coordinate to follow
        for (var j = 0; j < coordinates.length; j++) {
            currentGrid = coordinates[j];
            if (currentGrid == "") {
                currentGrid = {};
            }
            var xvalue = Math.floor(j / schemaTables.length);
            var yvalue = Math.floor(j % schemaTables.length)
            currentGrid["x"] = xvalue;
            currentGrid["y"] = yvalue;
            coordinates[j] = currentGrid;
        }

        //updates each rectangle for the heatmap
        var grid = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(coordinates, function(d) { return d; })
        //remove old grids and add new ones, this function works
        //when removing and adding grids
        grid.exit().remove();
        grid.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return d.x * gridSize.width })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d.y * gridSize.height})
            .attr("rx", 8)
            .attr("ry", 8)
            .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
            .attr("class", "server bordered")
            .attr("width", gridSize.width)
            .attr("height", gridSize.height)
            .transition().duration(0)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                var medianRefresh;
                var color;

                if (!d.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
                    medianRefresh = undefined;
                }
                else {
                    medianRefresh = d.data.medianrefresh;
                }

                if (medianRefresh == 0) {
                    color = colors[6];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh == null || medianRefresh == undefined) {
                    color = "white"
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 0 && medianRefresh <= 300) {
                    color = colors[5];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 300 && medianRefresh <= 600) {
                    color = colors[4];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 600 && medianRefresh <= 900) {
                    color = colors[3];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 900 && medianRefresh <= 400) {
                    color = colors[2];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 400 && medianRefresh <= 500) {
                    color = colors[1];
                }
                else if (medianRefresh > 500) {
                    color = colors[0];
                }
                return color;
            })

        //Update titles within rectangles
        svg.select("rect").selectAll("title").remove();

        var title = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                var medianRefresh,
                    server,
                    schemaTable,
                    schema,
                    table;

                if (!d.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
                    medianRefresh = undefined;
                    server = servers[d.x];
                    schema = schemaTables[d.y].split(".")[0];
                    table = schemaTables[d.y].split(".")[1];
                }
                else {
                    medianRefresh = d.data.medianrefresh;
                    server = d.server;
                    schemaTable = d.schemaTable;
                    schema = schemaTable.split(".")[0];
                    table = schemaTable.split(".")[1];
                }

                var result = "Median Refresh: " + medianRefresh + "\nServer: " + server + "\nSchema: " + schema + "\nTable: " + table; 
                return result
            })
```

I'm new to d3.js so any tips would be helpful. Here is the code where I call the update function:

```
$("#filters").on("select2:select", function() {
    var filter = $("#filters option:selected").text();
    if (filter != "") {
        var filterInfo = getFilterInfo(filter)
        filter = true;
        heatmap.update(filter, filterInfo)
    }
    else {
        heatmap.update();
    }
})
```

QUESTION UPDATE:
I fixed my problem here's the fixed code:

```
        //x-axis labels
        var serverLabels = svg.selectAll(".serverLabel")
            .data(servers)

            serverLabels.enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "serverLabel mono")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize.width; }).attr("y", 0)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize.width / 2 + ", -6)")
                .attr("class", "serverLabel mono")
                .merge(serverLabels)
                .text(function (d) { return d; })

            serverLabels.exit().remove();


        //y-axis labels   
        var schemaTableLabels = svg.selectAll(".schemaTableLabel")
            .data(schemaTables);

            schemaTableLabels.enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "schemaLabel mono")
                .attr("x", 50).attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize.height; })
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize.height / 1.5 + ")")
                .attr("class", "schemaTableLabel mono")
                .merge(schemaTableLabels)
                .text(function(d) { return d; })

            schemaTableLabels.exit().remove();
```

Comment: [Description of mentioned error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length) is clear enough. `console.log(gridAmount)` when you setup array.

Comment: It gives me a number everytime

Comment: Initially 14940. After applying the first filter that brings the row count down the gridAmount is 166. Taking away that filter which should bring the heatmap back to it's initial size I get gridAmount is NaN, the error, and then it logs 14940 again which leads me to believe that it is executing the code below the get functions before they are done getting the information that it needs.

Comment: @Kadeo13 the problem here is just the chaining of `.exit().enter()`, which is incorrect. To learn how to create a proper "enter" and "exit" selections, please study this example from Mike Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: I actually fixed my problem already, that was part of it, let me update my question so others can see.